# Excluding first Sheet in a Google Apps Script in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I am a complete rookie, and I wanted to make a dropdown menu in my 'Google Sheets Sales Pipeline', so I can easily sort my leads in regards to what stage they are in.

This does work, however, I need to be able to query all the leads from all the other sheets into a sort of "Master" sheet that is the first Sheet, and that is called 'NXT: Forside'.

When I make the query in my master sheet now, it just puts all the leads into the sheets with the corresponding name.

So what I need, is for my script to completely ignore Sheet 1 called 'NXT: Forside'.

This is what I have:

```
function onEdit(e){
  let range = e.range;
  let col = range.getColumn();
  let row = range.getRow();
  let val = range.getValue();
  let source = e.source.getActiveSheet();

  if (col == 1 && val != ''){
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = ss.getSheetByName(source.getName());
    let targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(val);
    let data = sheet.getRange(row,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    targetSheet.appendRow(data[0]);
    sheet.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Also is there a way to make this work on a mobile phone in the Google Sheets app?

Hopefully someone can help me out!

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,

Simon

I tried to add an exclusion code, but I don't think I did it right, because it did not work.

Comment: About your 1st question `So what I need, is for my script to completely ignore Sheet 1 called 'NXT: Forside'.`, in this case, how about modifying `if (col == 1 && val != ''){` to `if (col == 1 && val != '' && source.getSheetName() != "NXT: Forside"){`? About your 2nd question, unfortunately, I cannot understand `a mobile phone in the Google Sheets app`. Unfortunately, I cannot understand one of your 2 questions. So, I posted only an answer to your 1st question as a comment. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Answer (score 0):

let shts = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().filter((sh ,i) => i > 0).map(sh => sh)